# How to resolve a Classloader related 'java.lang.LinkageError' when sending email from Tomee?

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I am trying to send an email from my code that runs on Tomee 1.6

I have the following entry in the tomee.xml file.

```
    <Resource
    id="abc_mail"
    type="javax.mail.Session"
    >
        mail.transport.protocol=smtp
        mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
        mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
        mail.smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
        mail.smtp.port=465
        mail.smtp.auth=true
        mail.smtp.user=xyz@gmail.com
        password=xyzpass
    </Resource>
```

I have an ejb with the following declaration.

```
@Resource(name = "abc_mail")//, type = javax.mail.Session.class)
Session abcMailSession;
```

The code for sending the email is the following.

```
public void sendMessage(String addressTo, String subject, String messageText) {
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(abcMailSession);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("abc@xyz.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(addressTo));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(messageText);

            Transport.send(message);

            logger.info("Message sent successfully.");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

When calling this method I get the following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.apache.geronimo.mail.util.SessionUtil.getBooleanProperty(Ljavax/mail/Session;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z" the class loader (instance of org/apache/openejb/util/classloader/URLClassLoaderFirst) of the current class, javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/StandardClassLoader) for resolved class, org/apache/geronimo/mail/util/SessionUtil, have different Class objects for the type vax/mail/Session;Ljava/lang/String;Z)Z used in the signature
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.isStrictAddressing(MimeMessage.java:1460)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.addRecipientsToList(MimeMessage.java:428)
at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAllRecipients(MimeMessage.java:400)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:48)
at co.uk.dakia.core.interfaces.impl.NotificationManagerImpl.sendMessage(NotificationManagerImpl.java:88)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:180)
at org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:99)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:182)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:164)
at org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:80)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:212)
at org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:181)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:268)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:263)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:86)
at org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:303)
... 47 more
```

**Why do I get this error?** I am not able to figure out the first line in the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved this. The error occurs because the same class is being loaded by two different classloaders (tomcat and openejb ones), the class in question is javax.mail.Session
I added the following property to tomee's system.properties file

```
openejb.classloader.forced-skip=javax.mail
```

What this does it prevents openejb classloader from loading the javax.mail classes and therefore only tomcat classloader loads all the relevant classes required for sending email.

Comment: tomee already comes with javamail. are you including it in your project too?

Comment: No, I am using libraries that come with Tomee (as is). No additional libraries in my classpath. i.e. expect for EclipseLink etc... that are not part of Tomee.

Comment: that's strange. I work with tomee+ 1.6.0 and I use tomee built-in java mail support and I've never come up with this kind of error

Comment: This is what I am doing. 1) I get a call into a rest api running on one instance of tomee (sepparate port etc...). 2) Rest api calls a stateless EJB running on another instance of tomee, that puts a message on a Queue. 3) An mdb (running on same instance as the ejb) picks up the message and sends out an email. Fairly straight forward... I think.

Comment: are you using eclipse? maven? how are you packaging your app?

Comment: Eclipse --> Using tomcat server adapter to add the web projects. Using Export --> EAR to get the ear file then copying this to the apps folder in tomee (the ejb instance).